# Bootstrap constrain width div contained inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

SOLVED

I'm using Bootstrap to make a page navigation using images and a text and slightly opaque radial gradient hover. The issue I'm having is that the hover is slightly wider than the image it sits over so I get thin grey bars to the left and right of the image on hover. I've managed to get it looking alright when at full screen, but if I resize the page it gets off again.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 subnav" id="subnav1">
    <a href="#bands">
      <img src="_images/_thumbnails/niki_01_t.jpg" />
      <div id="subnav-overlay1" class="subnav-overlay">
        <h3 class="subnav-text" id="subnav-text1">BANDS</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 subnav" id="subnav2">
    <a href="#portraits">
      <img id="subnav-image2" src="_images/_thumbnails/terence_03_t.jpg" />
      <div id="subnav-overlay2" class="subnav-overlay">
        <h3 class="subnav-text" id="subnav-text2">PORTRAITS</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 subnav" id="subnav3">
    <a href="#products">
      <img src="_images/_thumbnails/bp_2_t.jpg" />
      <div id="subnav-overlay3" class="subnav-overlay">
        <h3 class="subnav-text" id="subnav-text3">PRODUCTS</h3>
      </div
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.subnav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.subnav img {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.subnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.subnav h3 {
  display: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.subnav-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    display:none;
    padding-right: -15px;
    padding-left: -15px;
}
```

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO4At.jpg)

Comment: Is .subnav-overlay the hover that appears? If so, have you attempted removing the left and right negative padding?

Comment: I added the left and right negative padding in an attempt to correct the issue. Without it there is no change.

Comment: Is there more CSS you could add to your example? Perhaps the hover state, and what you are doing at desktop to add your spacing between the subnav/columns

Comment: The hover is a jQuery .fadeIn function and the spacing between the columns is native through the Bootstrap grid system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your `<a>`

```
.subnav a {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The reason being - the absolute positioning of the overlay will not adhere to the padding of the relatively positioned Bootstrap column, which comes with the extra 15px padding. By adding the position relative to your `<a>` which is confined in the padding, you are keeping the absolute overlay within the size of the `<a>`

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqazqX)

Note that above I changed the column class to `col-md-4`, but that should not be relevant for you.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your help Stu!

Comment: @HunterBoen you should accept the answer if it solved your problem :)